# R function using . and ~

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to learn to use `~` and `.` in R.

In the code below is the same function written with and without the use of `~` and `.`.I didn't understand what happened in the first function to appear the error.

```
#FIRST FUNCTION
col_summary2 <- function(.x, .f, ...){
  .x <- purrr::keep(.x, is.numeric)
  purrr::map_dbl(.x, ~.f(., ...))
}

col_summary2(mtcars,mean) #Error in mean.default(., ...) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one

#SECOND FUNCTION
col_summary2 <- function(.x, .f, ...){
  .x <- purrr::keep(.x, is.numeric)
  purrr::map_dbl(.x, function(x) .f(x, ...))
}

col_summary2(mtcars,mean) #mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs      am       gear       carb
                          #20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750   0.437500 0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

Comment: You could also do: `col_summary2 <- function(.x, .f, ...) {
  .x <- purrr::keep(.x, is.numeric) ; 
  purrr::map_dbl(.x, .f, ...)
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case your argument is passed to `purrr::as_mapper` internally:

```
as_mapper(~f(., ...))
# function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) 
#   f(., ...)
```

Which means it behaves just as if you had written :

```
purrr::map_dbl(.x, function(..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) f(., ...))
```

The function that is created has a `...` argument, (it always has, it would even if `.f` didn't have it).

The `.x`, `.y`, and `.` arguments are actually extracted from the `...`, as `..1` means "first thing stuffed into `...`", `..2` means "second thing..." and so on.

So in your first case `.x` is passed through `...` and ends up in  `.` as well.

```
col_summary3 <- function(.x, .f, ...){
  .x <- purrr::keep(.x, is.numeric)
  purrr::map_dbl(.x, ~{print(list(...));.f(., ...)})
}
col_summary3(mtcars,mean) 
# [[1]]
# [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4
# [17] 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
#  Error in mean.default(., ...) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

`.x` ends up being fed both to the first argument of `.f` and to the second through `.f(.,...)`, so it ends up in the second argument of `mean.default`, i.e. `trim`, which doesn't like it.

It's not the case in your second function, where the `...` argument (not used in this case) is smoothly passed from the initial call to the `.f` call.

***Re "So, in this case, I can't use ~ and ., right?"***

You can't use it directly as there is a conflict with `...`. You can go around it however by passing it to the `.y` argument and use `purr::invoke`, but that's very mean for the next person that will have to read it :).

```
col_summary4 <- function(.x, .f, ...){
  .x <- purrr::keep(.x, is.numeric)
  purrr::map_dbl(.x, ~ invoke(.f, .y, .), .y=list(...))
}

col_summary4(mtcars,mean) 
# mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs         am       gear       carb 
# 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750   0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500 

col_summary4(mtcars,mean, trim = 0.3)
# mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
# 19.1785714   6.4285714 214.5071429 136.2857143   3.5971429   3.2467857  17.7600000   0.3571429   0.2857143   3.5714286   2.6428571
```

Comment: It's not so easy to articulate in a simple way :). Let me know if it makes sense or where I lose you.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've got it. So, in this case, I can't use `~` and `.`, right?