# R - Use all non-zero fractions in a data frame as probabilities for replacing themselves with sample()

Tags: r, probability

I have an R `tibble` called `my_data` which is composed of either (1) zeros, or (2) numbers between zero and one:

```
> my_data
# A tibble: 30 x 40
      s1    s2    s3    s4    s5    s6    s7    s8    s9   s10   s11   s12   s13
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0 0.969     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2     0     0     0     0     0     0 0         0     0     0     0     0     0
 3     0     0     0     0     0     0 0         0     0     0     0     0     0
 4     0     0     0     0     0     0 0         0     0     0     0     0     0
 5     0     0     0     0     0     0 0         0     0     0     0     0     0
 6     0     0     0     0     0     0 0         0     0     0     0     0     0
 7     0     0     0     0     0     0 0         0     0     0     0     0     0
 8     0     0     0     0     0     0 0         0     0     0     0     0     0
 9     0     0     0     0     0     0 0         0     0     0     0     0     0
10     0     0     0     0     0     0 0         0     0     0     0     0     0
# ... with 20 more rows, and 27 more variables: s14 <dbl>, s15 <dbl>, s16 <dbl>,
#   s17 <dbl>, s18 <dbl>, s19 <dbl>, s20 <dbl>, s21 <dbl>, s22 <dbl>, s23 <dbl>,
#   s24 <dbl>, s25 <dbl>, s26 <dbl>, s27 <dbl>, s28 <dbl>, s29 <dbl>, s30 <dbl>,
#   s31 <dbl>, s32 <dbl>, s33 <dbl>, s34 <dbl>, s35 <dbl>, s36 <dbl>, s37 <dbl>,
#   s38 <dbl>, s39 <dbl>, s40 <dbl>
```

I want to replace all the non-zero numbers in `my_data` (such as 0.969 in column `s7`) with 1s at a certain probability where the numbers *themselves* are the probabilities, otherwise they get replaced with 0s. For example, there is a 0.969 probability that the *number* 0.969 (in the column named `s7`) will be replaced by 1, and a 0.031 probability that it will be replaced by 0.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
# Doesn't work:
my_data %>% 
    mutate_all(function(x) {
        case_when(x == 0 ~ 0, 
                  x > 0 ~ sample(0:1, size = 1, prob = c(1 - x, x)))
    })
```

How do I do this? Should I be using `purrr::map()` (how?) or something else? Thank you!

Here is the `dput()` of `my_data`:

```
structure(list(s1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.956159271283707, 0), s3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.982878394164842, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.982878394164842), s4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.959674748019852, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.959674748019852, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.876892497722416, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.876892497722416, 0, 0), s6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.989641778880238, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.989641778880238, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s7 = c(0.969355168732184, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.969355168732184, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.991517098892877, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.991517098892877, 
0, 0, 0, 0.991517098892877, 0.991517098892877), s9 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.929770500656618, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.929770500656618, 0, 0), s10 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.993637560789263, 
0), s12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.949340969426271, 0, 0, 0.949340969426271, 
0, 0), s13 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.919919910704918, 0), s14 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.937896138681889, 
0, 0, 0.937896138681889, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s15 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.991517098892877, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.991517098892877), s16 = c(0.956159271283707, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.956159271283707, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.956159271283707, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.956159271283707, 
0.956159271283707), s17 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.597187792371775, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.597187792371775, 0), s18 = c(0.975209130375021, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.975209130375021, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.975209130375021), s19 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s20 = c(0.937234650859115, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.937234650859115, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.937234650859115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s21 = c(0.929770500656618, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.929770500656618, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.929770500656618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.929770500656618, 
0), s22 = c(0.929770500656618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.929770500656618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.929770500656618), s23 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.921445826350068), s24 = c(0.919919910704918, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), s25 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.993637560789263, 0), 
    s26 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.942968974602997, 0.942968974602997
    ), s27 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.959674748019852, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s28 = c(0.999498946154851, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s29 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.988925875658174, 0), s30 = c(0, 0.975209130375021, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.975209130375021, 0), s31 = c(0.986350500013957, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.986350500013957, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.986350500013957
    ), s32 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.942968974602997, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.942968974602997), 
    s33 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.927760110879459, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s34 = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.919919910704918, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.919919910704918, 0, 0, 0.919919910704918, 
    0, 0), s35 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.956159271283707, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.956159271283707, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.956159271283707, 0), s36 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.991517098892877, 0, 0.991517098892877, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.991517098892877, 0.991517098892877, 
    0), s37 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.919919910704918, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.919919910704918, 
    0), s38 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s39 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.999972102622884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), s40 = c(0.942968974602997, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.942968974602997, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try :

```
library(tidyverse)
as_tibble(apply(df, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1,prob=c(1-x,x))))
```

It's usually discouraged to convert from matrix to data.frame but here it seems you really have a matrix formatted as a data.frame so I went for it.

To avoid the conversion you could do:

```
df %>% mutate_all(~ map_dbl(.,~sample(c(0,1),1,prob=c(1-.x,.x))))
```

The following will test the value before sampling, but I'm not sure if it'll be much faster or any faster:

```
df %>% mutate_all(~ map_if(.,~. != 0, ~sample(c(0,1),1,prob=c(1-.x,.x))) %>% unlist)
```

Comment: Thank you @Moody_Mudskipper, both the `apply` and `map` solutions worked for me. However, what does the `~` signify in the `mutate_all()` and `map()`? I thought `~`s are used in formulae for models?

Comment: It's the formula notation, or shorthand notation used by `tidyverse` packages and especially `purrr`. typing `~ 1 + .x` is equivalent to typing `function(x) 1+x`. You can use the traditional notation as well in `tidyverse` functions  but the shorthand is really handy.

Comment: This post goes more in details on the formula notation and the function `purr::as_mapper`, only if you're interested in diving in the more technical aspects : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362474/r-function-using-and/51362701#51362701

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to sample from a binomial distribution. Fortunately `rbinom` is vectorized regarding its `prob` parameter and you can avoid any R loops (`for`, `apply`, `Vectorize`, etc.).

```
m <- as.matrix(DF)
set.seed(42) #for reproducibility
m[m != 0] <- rbinom(sum(m != 0), 1, m[m != 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use runif:

```
df %>%
  map_df(~ if_else(runif(length(.x)) < .x, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Can you please explain the `runif(.x) < .x` condition? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: That's a mistake, you are right. should be `runif(length(.x))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use your custom function (with `case_when`) you can do

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) {
    case_when(x == 0 ~ 0L, 
              x > 0 ~ sample(0:1, size = 1, prob = c(1 - x, x)))
  })
```

Or

```
f = function(x) {
  case_when(x == 0 ~ 0L, 
            x > 0 ~ sample(0:1, size = 1, prob = c(1 - x, x))) }
f = Vectorize(f)

df %>% mutate_all(f)
```

You had 2 issues with your approach.

1) Your function wasn't vectorized and was considering the whole columns of probabilities. The error was `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: incorrect number of probabilities.` Using `rowwise` or vectorising your function will solve this.

2) `case_when` didn't return values of the same type. The error was `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: must be type double, not integer.` Using `0L` insted of `0` will solve this.